# How to convert a command line string to hwnd in C++?

Tags: c++, c, command-line-arguments, screensaver, hwnd

I want to create a screen saver in C++ using OpenGL. The command line sent to my app for previewing the screen saver in a small window contains a number which is the `hwnd` of the small monitor window in screen saver control panel applet. how can I convert this string to a valid `hwnd`?

Answer (score 5):

From [INFO: Screen Saver Command Line Arguments](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182383):

> `<HWND>` is a HWND presented on the command line as an unsigned decimal number.

So, convert the decimal number to an `unsigned int` and then cast to `HWND`. For example:

```
(HWND)atoi(argv[n])
```

where `argv[n]` is the argument where the HWND value is found.

<sub>Pedant's corner: My use of `atoi()` can probably be improved, since the number on the command line is unsigned. Feel free.</sub>

Comment: Duct Tape Programmer (TM)- certified design :)

Comment: here it is: HWND h = atoi(argv[5]);